# Chrome Instability on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

For the past couple of weeks I have been noticing a lot of instability in Google Chrome. About once a day the entire application will either become totally unresponsive, or alternatively it continues to work, but repaints of the UI stop happening (clicking on different tabs changes the title of the window, but the page remains the same).

Has anybody experienced these issues and found any ways to improve the stability? I install all the updates as they come in, so any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A reply to an earlier version of this question suggested pressing **Shift-Esc** while in Chrome, which brings up a **Chrome Task Manager** window, and **ending** all **processes** except the Browser itself and the GPU Process.

I tried this, and **it worked** for me. The results imply that one of those processes is causing the problem, and my guess would be that a third-party developer hasn't properly tested its product in the Ubuntu Linux environment, and probably the product is not "**well behaved**" according to **Google's rules for developing Chrome Extensions**.

**Ending tasks leaves them ended** until you go back into the menu for Extensions and **reactivate** them. I don't have time to add extensions back systematically to identify which causes the problem. Some of my extensions needed deleting anyway, but I will systematically add those I need back one by one, and if I find an extension that brings the problem back, I'll post that information here.